# Gmail API : resultSizeEstimate gives odd numbers

Tags: api, google-api, gmail, google-api-php-client, gmail-api

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list

The Gmail API allows to retrieve an estimate for the number of message for a given query (from:send1@gmail.com is:unread). Somehow the number that the API returns seems very different from the one shown on the webmail.

Any idea on how to return the actual number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

resultSizeEstimate is only an estimate and isn't guaranteed to be accurate for general queries.  It should give more reasonable (still estimated) numbers for queries on specific labels ("label:MYLABEL" or "label:MYLABEL is:unread").

Unfortunately, there currently isn't a method of getting the actual numbers, other than retrieving all of them and looking at the size of the list returned.

Comment: The issue is related to 103. For some reason my app started to limit results to 103 messages in any mailbox. No matter what is my query.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer - I was hitting the 103 limit as well.

I've noticed that by playing with the maxResults parameter of the Google API I get different, yet still invalid, results.

With this value of maxResults:

```python
request = service.users().messages().list(userId=user_id, labelIds=formatted_labels)
```

--> resultSizeEstimate = 103

With this value of maxResults:

```python
request = service.users().messages().list(userId=user_id, labelIds=formatted_labels, maxResults=100)
```

--> resultSizeEstimate = 103

With this value of maxResults:

```python
request = service.users().messages().list(userId=user_id, labelIds=formatted_labels, maxResults=1000)
```

--> resultSizeEstimate = 511

With this value of maxResults:

```python
request = service.users().messages().list(userId=user_id, labelIds=formatted_labels, maxResults=50)
```

--> resultSizeEstimate = 52

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly the solution to all cases but it may help. You can get the exact number of emails under a given label using Users.labels:get

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/get

The messagesTotal value gives you that number.

Unfortunately, as others notice, listing messages with Users.messages:list or doing a search do not return accurate results.